# Как отправить через formData массив объектов со вложенным объектом

Tags: javascript

Отправляю через `formData` массив объектов следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема с отправкой поля `tags` - в значение ключа почему-то идёт `object Object`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обработка отправляемого массива объектов:

```
for (let key in addTagsResultsObj) {
  if (key === 'operations_ids') {
     documentsIDArr.forEach((id, idx) => {
        formdata.append(`operations_ids[${idx}]`, id);
     });
  } else if (key === 'tags') {
     addedTagsArr.forEach((item, idx) => {
        formdata.append(`tags[${idx}]`, item);
     });
  } else {
       formdata.append(key, addTagsResultsObj[key]);
    }
  }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне правильно отправить эти вложенные объекты?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score -2):

```
let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('key1', ...);
                formData.append('key2', ...);
                formData.append('...', ...);
                formData.append('keyN', ...);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://your/url/here.html.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: (response) => {
                       ...
                    },
                    error: (response) => {
                           ...
                    },
                })
                .done(() => {
                    // If need to update data
                    formData.delete('key1');
                    formData.delete('key2');
                    formData.delete('...');
                    formData.delete('keyN');
                });
```